# how do you use the IF COMMAND to convert a date from 5/1/2017 to 05012017 in microsoft access?

Tags: ms-access-2010

how do you use the IF COMMAND to convert a date from 5/1/2017 to 05012017 in microsoft access?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take few moments to take a [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to get better answers for your questions

Answer (score 1):

You don't. *Format* is for this if month is May:

```
TextDate = Format(YourDateValue, "mmddyyyy")
```

or, if month is January:

```
TextDate = Format(YourDateValue, "ddmmyyyy")
```